# Zend Developer Tools Bluemix ZF2 throwing error 500

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, developer-tools, ibm-cloud

Have a question about `zdt module`. So I have looked at the documentation for Doctrine and ZF2 (also Marco Pivetti tutorial ), that's when I find out about zdt, and all is working like a charm on `localhost`, but when I transfer the project to `IBM bluemix` server, the module **ZendDeveloperTools is throwing server error 500** (know that because when I comment this name in modules in `application.config` file it's working ok, but without the zdt).

I have installed it all via composer, and copy to autoload files, and all that is said in tutorials, but it's not working. Does anyone had this kind of problem on IBM's bluemix server ? I'm using the `cloudfoundry/php` buildpack with most of the modules enabled. Haven't worked with zdt so don't know where the problem might be.

Looked everywhere (even here in SO) but can't find the proper answer to my solution.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: it could be anything, like a missing component of php on the server, try to put on your index.php on top: ini_set('display_errors','on'); error_reporting(E_ALL); then it will show you the error, update your post with the error message, and we will be able to help :)

Comment: Thanks for the info about displaying error messages ( i didn't know how to display them on zf2 :) ) 
The errors are : 

( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in /home/vcap/app/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 1135

( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /home/vcap/app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php on line 43
But i'm using Cloudant Bluemix NoSql service,and have db params in autoload/local

Comment: 'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            // default connection name
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host'     => 'host-from-cloudant',
                    'port'     => 'port-from-cloudant',
                    'user'     => 'user-from-cloudant',
                    'password' => 'pass-from-cloudant',
                    'dbname'   => 'dbname',
                )
            )
        )
    ),
this is inside local.php.dist

Comment: this: Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Drive is for Mysql... what NoSql service are you using Mongo DB?

Comment: I'm using IBM's Cloudant NoSql and was thinking to use doctrineCouchDb project ? But do i need the bluemix service to bind it with cloudant ? it's not stand alone service ?

Comment: think so, never used Doctrine, but if you are not using mysql, you have to change the adapter to be the one that you are using, now, I can't believe that it was ok on your local server and now is not on the remote server..

Comment: I'll google a little about how to connect Doctrine and NoSql :) btw thanks about the help :) ( i'll comment if i found out something :) ) just to be there, you never know who's gonna maybe need it :)

Comment: Answer the question and mark your answer rather than commenting -  once you figure it out.

Comment: Could you answer your question and mark it as answered?

Comment: @JeffSloyer  Haven't find the solution yet, so i returned to zf1 :(  But will answer when i take a deeper look into it ....

Comment: @crazy_ljuba just following up here...

Comment: @crazy_ljuba are you still having this issue?

Comment: Currently not able to take a look at this :( And any time soon, so if you found out something please send it here :)

Answer (score 0):

according to what you specified in your comments, the error 500 is related to the DB Connection config you are using in Doctrine ORM:
your config is using PDO_MYSQL driver and it is not available by default on PHP runtime in Bluemix (you have to specify in composer.json dependencies if you want to use it in PHP runtime on Bluemix)

Regarding what you are looking for in your following comments, Doctrine 2 supports NoSQL ODM on MongoDB and CouchDB
Here you can find all the documentation for Doctrine ODM over MongoDB

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/